# how get files with GmailApi - AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

i want to get files of my emails with an script, i can get size, name, etc,, but i can donwload or copy to my drive these files?

```
 function TestFils(){
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 20);
var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
    var attachments = msgs[i][j].getAttachments();
    for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
      Logger.log('Message "%s" contains the attachment "%s" (%s bytes)',
                 msgs[i][j].getSubject(), attachments[k].getName(), attachments[k].getSize());
      if (attachments[k].getName().match(/.jpg*/))
           attachments[k].getAs("image/jpeg");
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your script, `attachments` is the file blob. So you can download it to your Google Drive using the file blob. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function TestFils(){
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 20);
  var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
      var attachments = msgs[i][j].getAttachments();
      for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
        Logger.log('Message "%s" contains the attachment "%s" (%s bytes)',
        msgs[i][j].getSubject(), attachments[k].getName(), attachments[k].getSize());
        if (attachments[k].getName().match(/.jpg*/)) {
          DriveApp.createFile(attachments[k]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note :

In this sample, attachment files are downloaded to root folder on your Google Drive. If you want to download files to the specific folder, please use `DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(attachments[k]);` instead of `DriveApp.createFile(attachments[k]);`.

Comment: thank you, but i want download files in localserver, i do this  getting file link an downloading with window.locations, thank you very much

Comment: @Andress Blend I have misunderstand your question. I have thought that "my drive" in your question is your Google Drive. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Can I ask you one question for what you want? How do you want to use the file link?